# Add an alpha channel and color profile to image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get an image with an alpha channel and a color profile of sRGB IEC61966-2.1.

The image I am starting with does not have an alpha channel but it does have the color profile I want. see [starting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6yXX.png)

If I run the following,

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('84.png')
print(img.mode)
img.convert('RGBA').save('84a.png')
```

I get an alpha channel, but the color profile seems to be gone. see [ending image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq0tN.png). Note that img.mode is 'P'. I saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013794/python-apply-srgb-colour-profile-and-alpha-channel-to-image), but I would like to do it without cv2 if possible. Also I think that solution is starting with an image that already has an alpha channel. Maybe it applies and I am missing something.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PIL/Pillow decode icc profile information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865743/pil-pillow-decode-icc-profile-information)

Comment: Hello @HansHirse, I tried that as well. However, for some reason when I run `Image.open(path).info.get('icc_profile')` on my image I get `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855022/conversion-from-cmyk-to-rgb-with-pillow-is-different-from-that-of-photoshop) helped to figure it out. All I did was find my desired *.icc file at `/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/`. I copied it to my run directory and called it `sRGB.icc`. Then I ran

```
from PIL import Image, ImageCms
img = Image.open('84.png').convert('RGBA')
img = ImageCms.profileToProfile(img, 'sRGB.icc', 'sRGB.icc', renderingIntent=0, outputMode='RGBA')
img.save('84a.png')
```

This gave me the alpha channel and color profile I wanted. However, it is a little 'hacky' since `profileToProfile()` should convert from one profile to another. Python returns `None` when I run `Image.open('84.png').info.get('icc_profile')` so there seems to be no initial color profile recognized.